# Backbone - Hashtag appearing at very end of URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am doing my first Backbone project.  I am using Backbone 1.3.3 and Underscore 1.8.3.  I am having a problem with my router.  When I invoke the router, it places the hashtag at the very end of the URL:

```
http://server:9999/backbone_demo/addMember#
```

instead of:

```
http://server:9999/backbone_demo/#addMember
```

which is what I want.

```
var router = null;
var context = "backbone_demo";

DemoRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        initializeEventsForNavigation();
    },
    routes: {"" : "start", "/bands": "bands", "/addMember": "addMember", "*defaultRoute" : "defaultRoute"},

    defaultRoute: function() {
        this.start();
    },
    start: function () {
        this.bands();
    },
    bands: function () {
        BackboneDemo.View.unrenderAllViews();
        BackboneDemo.View.renderBandList();
    },
    addMember: function() {
        BackboneDemo.View.unrenderAllViews();
        BackboneDemo.View.renderAddMember();
    }


});

var init = function() {
    initializeEventsForBandListRender();
    initializeEventsForAddMemberRender();
    router = new DemoRouter();
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: context});

};

var navigate = function(e) {
    var route = e.detail.route;
    router.navigate("/" + route, true);
};
```

If I pass "addMember" to my navigate function (in e.detail.route), I will be passing "/addMember" to router.navigate.  The router works fine except for this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set `pushState` to `false` if you want to use hash routing.

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: false, root: context});
```

Comment: Tried it out.  This broke my router.  Now all routes go to http://server:9999/backbone_demo/#

Comment: Working through it.  I am having trouble with a CustomEvent calling my navigate function.

Comment: Ok, my event handling was screwing me up.  Working now!